# Connect a laptop to VPN without logging in

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I have a strange problem, but first, let me describe the network:

Our corporate network has an AD servers on it. We were given corporate laptops that you need to be physically connected the first time in order to use (so when you attempt to log in for the first time, it authenticates via the AD server and downloads your profile). Once you've logged in for the first time, I can then take it home and log in locally, then use Cisco AnyConnect in order to access the corporate network (authenticated using a certificate that must be logged into, similar to an SSH keyfile). This works great.
Problem is, I've been given a second corporate laptop that I need to be able to log into, but, as I live fairly far from the nearest corporate access point, I have no way to log into it.

I have tried logging onto the corporate network via my home pc and sharing the internet connection (using internet connection sharing) through my nic card (I have 1 nic and 1 wifi on it), but it won't connect. I'm out of ideas. That's pretty much as far as I've gotten.

The laptop that I can use (call it laptop 1) I have reduced access to, so I can't change any of the configuration on it (so it can only be an endpoint, which is why I've been trying to use my home machine).

These are the weapons I have at my disposal. My home PC and both laptops are running windows 7:

Home PC
 - 2x Network cards
 - 1x usb wifi dongle
 - Corporate network access

Home Server (Laptop running Centos)
 - 1x network card
 - 1x wifi
 - only local access

Laptop 1
 - 1x network card
 - 1x wifi
 - Corporate network access
 - Can log in

Laptop 2
 - 1x network card
 - 1x wifi
 - Can't log in without wired access to corporate network

Cisco cable modem with 4 ethernet ports (Can't do much with this. No VPN option here)

D-Link 8 port switch
Belkin wifi router with 4 ethernet ports (not being used, and can't do VPN with it)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if it wasn't set up by the IT department to let you run the VPN before logging into Windows, there won't be a way. You need it to connect to the VPN to download your credentials first.

My advice is to either ship it back and ask for them to make it an always-on VPN connection (if possible with their VPN server), or wait until you can drive in. Option two, is send it to someone at one of the branches, have them log in and run a remote control program - Maybe VNC, or even Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP for Microsoft). Then, you connect remotely, and enter your credentials at the Windows login screen. It will log you in, then you log it out and ask them to ship it back to you.

Due to the nature of a VPN, it is rare for the "client" programs to be allowed to share that "private" connection via ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) in Windows. Because of this, I doubt any sort of setup with your current laptop would allow your second one to log in for this first, crucial login.